# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on a Split String in a array

Tags: java, string

So I am doing some problems on the UVa online problem judge, but on a relativity easy problem, I keep on getting a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. To understand the code, here is the [problem.](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=607&page=show_problem&problem=3834)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = scan.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= t; i++){
        String d = scan.nextLine();
        if (d.equals("report")) {
            System.out.println(sum);
        } else {
            String[] parts = d.split(" ");
            int z = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
            sum+=z;
        }
    }
}
}
```

The error message is:

```
reportException in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

And I am using the sample input given.

Edit:
I have already tried added println statements in the code and figured out that the number is not being read. I am trying to understand why.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? The exception describes what's going on pretty darn well...

Comment: Check what `d` contains, and make sure there are actually two items in the array after the `split`.

Comment: The exception tells you what line the error occurs on and what the bogus array index is.  Either use your interactive debugger or add `System.out.println` statements to determine how big the array is at that point and why you're generating an index larger than the array.  This is basic debugging stuff that you need to learn.  SO is not here to do your debugging for you.

Comment: What do you mean by "the number is not being read"? The number is not in `d` at all? The number's not being parsed by `Integer.parseInt(parts[1])`? Be specific.

Comment: Ok, the number is in d, but is not being allocated into parts[1]. I tried System.out.println(parts[0]), and it prints out: donate. But when I try System.out.println(parts[1]), it gives me the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error.

Comment: Then it appears that the split isn't working the way you want it to. In the debugger, what is `d` and the entire contents of `parts`?

Comment: d is donate k, where k is a number (100 ≤ k ≤ 10^5). Since I am spliting the d on the space into parts, it should give me the number on parts[1]. But this is not happening. The entire contents of parts is currently: {"donate"}.

Comment: What happens if you split on "\\s+" instead of " "? I find it strange that you're inputting something with a space yet the space doesn't seem to be detected (and the rest of the input appears to be cut off, in fact...)

Comment: How *exactly* are you formatting your input? input on one line, then "donate ___" on the next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after some messing around on my machine I think I found what might be at least part of the problem. The issue is that I'm not sure what the precise input is, so I'm going off of what I could get working on my machine.

So you start up your program, and it waits for a prompt at this line:

```
int t = scan.nextInt();
```

You enter your integer, and the program moves on as expected:

```
Input: 100 // Then press enter to continue
```

The input is parsed, and now `t` is set to 100.

Then when your program enters your `for` loop, it comes across this line:

```
String d = scan.nextLine();
```

Yet for some reason the program doesn't wait for input! (Or at least it didn't on my machine)

I believe the issue lies here:

```
Input: 100 // Then press enter to continue
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What I think is happening is that your input is *really*

```
Input: 100\n
          ^^
```

That character (`\r\n` on Windows) is what's input when you hit enter. It's a newline character that tells the console to go to the next line.

So as a result, what I think happens is this:

```
Input: 100\n
```

Scanner parses `100`, *leaving the `\n` in the input stream*

Then at the `nextLine()` call, the scanner sees `\n` on the input stream, which denotes *end of line*, so it thinks you already input the entire line! Because what it thought was your input was only the newline character, it returns an empty string, because your "input" was an empty string and the newline character. Your program then goes to split the newline character by spaces, rightly returns an array with a single element, and then your program promptly crashes when accessing an out-of-bounds index.

What might work better is reading an entire line first and parsing the integer so your scanner doesn't get ahead of itself, like this:

```
int t = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
```

Just as a warning: This is what I've been able to come up with based on using OP's code as-is on my machine. I was unable to get a situation where the only element in `parts` was `"donate"`. I will update further as I get more info.

Comment: Ok, I saw this too, but did not know that that was the problem, and that `int t = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());` would solve that problem. After doing this and a slight error I had here: `for (int i = 0; i <= t; i++){` (It was supposed to be `for (int i = 0; i < t; i++){)`, I submitted it and it got accepted. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. Sorry for being a harsh at first, I wasn't expecting the problem to be something a bit strange like this.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means the array `parts`'s length less than 2, sometimes.
It means the variable `d` does not **always** contain the string **BLANK SPACE**, " ", what you split by.

try this code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = scan.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= t; i++){
        String d = scan.nextLine();
        if (d.equals("report")) {
            System.out.println(sum);
        } else {
            String[] parts = d.split(" ");
            /*
             * Add IF statement,
             */
            if (parts.length() > 1) {
                int z = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
                sum+=z;
            }

        }
    }
}
}
```